# Run HelloWorld Application from Titanium

Tags: android, titanium

I am very new to Titanium. I created a HelloWorld Application on Titanium. And Trying to run it on Android Device connected to my computer. But when I trying to run the application on device it shows some errors like

> [INFO] logfile = C:\Titanium\Workspace\HelloWorld\build.log
>   [DEBUG] C:\Documents and Settings\xxx\Application Data\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.0.0.GA\android\builder.py install HelloWorld C:\AndroidSDk\android-sdk-windows C:\Titanium\Workspace\HelloWorld com.titanium.helloworld 1
>   [DEBUG] detected module analytics, path = C:\Documents and Settings\xxx\Application Data\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-analytics.jar
>   [DEBUG] detected module android, path = C:\Documents and Settings\xxx\Application Data\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-android.jar
>   [DEBUG] adding required library: jaxen-1.1.1.jar
>   [DEBUG] adding required library: ti-commons-codec-1.3.jar
>   [DEBUG] adding required library: kroll-common.jar
>   [DEBUG] adding required library: titanium.jar
>   [DEBUG] detected module app, path = C:\Documents and Settings\xxx\Application Data\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-app.jar
>   [DEBUG] detected module ui, path = C:\Documents and Settings\xxx\Application Data\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-ui.jar
>   [DEBUG] adding required library: android-support-v4.jar
>   [DEBUG] detected module filesystem, path = C:\Documents and Settings\xxx\Application Data\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-filesystem.jar
>   [DEBUG] detected module media, path = C:\Documents and Settings\xxx\Application Data\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-media.jar
>   [DEBUG] detected module locale, path = C:\Documents and Settings\xxx\Application Data\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-locale.jar
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Documents and Settings\xxx\Application Data\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.0.0.GA\android\builder.py", line 2324, in 
>       builder = Builder(project_name,sdk_dir,project_dir,template_dir,app_id)
>     File "C:\Documents and Settings\xxx\Application Data\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.0.0.GA\android\builder.py", line 362, in **init**
>       android_creator.create(parent_dir, project_dir=self.top_dir, build_time=True)
>     File "C:\Documents and Settings\xxx\Application Data\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.0.0.GA\android\android.py", line 344, in create
>       self.build_modules_info(resource_dir, app_bin_dir, include_all_ti_modules=include_all_ti_modules)
>     File "C:\Documents and Settings\xxx\Application Data\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.0.0.GA\android\android.py", line 170, in build_modules_info
>       compiler.compile(compile_bytecode=False, info_message=None)
>     File "C:\Documents and Settings\xxx\Application Data\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.0.0.GA\android\compiler.py", line 271, in compile
>       for root, dirs, files in os.walk(self.project_dir, True, None, True):
>   TypeError: walk() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)

Comment: Try running Project->Clean in Titanium Studio and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. But it has make no effect to my problem. Still in the same status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by setting Environment Variable for JAVA_HOME and path. JAVA_HOME - C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_25 and path - C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin. Thanks...